# How can I convert a string in a list of lists into tuple?

Tags: python

```
list1 = [['a', (1, 1)], ['a', (1, 2)], ['a', (1, 3)]]
```

Suppose I need to replace first 'a' with `(0,1)`, then the outcome should be:

```
[[(0,1), (1, 1)], ['a', (1, 2)], ['a', (1, 3)]]
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Simply address the inner list:

```
list1[0][0] = (0, 1)
```

The first indexing operation `[0]` retrieves the first element in the outer list, to which you then apply *another* indexing operation to get the first element of the contained list.

```
>>> list1 = [['a', (1, 1)], ['a', (1, 2)], ['a', (1, 3)]]
>>> list1[0][0] = (0, 1)
>>> list1
[[(0, 1), (1, 1)], ['a', (1, 2)], ['a', (1, 3)]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> my_list = [['a', (1, 1)], ['a', (1, 2)], ['a', (1, 3)]]
>>> for sublist in my_list:
        if sublist[0] == 'a':
            sublist[0] = (0, 1)
            break


>>> my_list
[[(0, 1), (1, 1)], ['a', (1, 2)], ['a', (1, 3)]]
```

Comment: I don't think that it is a good idea to use a loop constuct if you don't want to loop through something.

Comment: @MaxPowers He said that he wanted to replace the **first** `'a'`, so I assumed he meant that in a general sense.

Comment: @MaxPowers: The question has enough ambiguity to allow for this answer to be correct too; my answer is the most obviously correct *if you know where the first `'a'` is located*. Otherwise, jamylak is correct by looking for it with a search.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: to make this answer the question (only the first 'a'), and to satisfy the unhappy indentation customers - here's some ok-ish code:

```
for inner_list in list1:
    for idx, elem in enumerate(inner_list):
        if elem=='a':
            inner_list[idx] = (0,1)
            break
```

Comment: No, the example output shows that only the first `'a'` needs to be replaced. Your code replaces *all* occurrences of `'a'`.

Comment: @GuyAdini add `break` and fix the pascal indenting!